# Create cross sections equally spaced in a poly line imported from QGIS to MATLAB?

Tags: qgis, line, matlab, cross-section

I had to create an Excel sheet with each profile cross-section which gave me the coordinates and elevations from a poly line of 2300 m length, referenced from 5 different DGM, which composed the study area. Each cross-section had different length and was spaced by eyelet roughly 100 m. I need now to space them by 5 m and I will get a really big data.

How can I create and export the cross sections profiles equally spaced and with the same length from the data above described?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, with enough details. Feel free to include a link to the other questions you have if it is relevant

Comment: @JGH is it ok now?

Comment: It's in the "reopen" pipeline. You may want to describe more what you have and want (ex: do you have the polyline and a DEM and want to sample it, or do you just have 2 points with altitude and want to do a linear interpolation between the two)

Comment: @JGH thank you. I think now is ok.